# Cache $resource api request globally for controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My angular application pretty much relies on one api call (for example `/api/example`).

I have multiple routes, modules, and controllers that need to use the data from that api request. For example I have:

```
public
|__feature1
  |__ feature1.controller.js
  |__ feature1.route.js
|__feature2
  |__ feature2.controller.js
  |__ feature2.route.js
|__core
  |__ core.controller.js
  |__ core.nav.controller.js
  |__ core.route.js
  |__ core.service.js
|__ app.js
```

Each of those feature controllers need the data from `/api/example`.

**An example of `core.service.js`**

```
angular.module('myApp')
.factory('MainService', ['$resource'
  function($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/example', {}, {
      get: {
        method: 'GET'
      }
    });
  }
]);
```

**Usually I would do something in `feature1/feature.controller.js`:**

```
angular.module('feature1')
.controller('Feature1Ctrl', ['MainService',
  function(MainService){
    MainService
      .get()
      .$promise
      .then(function(data){
        console.log(data);
      });
  }
]);
```

**And then I would do the same thing in `feature2/feature2.controller.js`**

```
angular.module('feature2')
.controller('Feature2Ctrl', ['MainService',
  function(MainService){
    MainService
      .get()
      .$promise
      .then(function(data){
        // do something with the SAME data again
        console.log(data);
      });
  }
]);
```

Is there a way that my application can immediately call the API and cache the request data so that the other controllers can get access to it **without having to make multiple requests.**

**So that I could essentially do something maybe like:**

```
angular.module('core')
.controller('NavCtrl', ['MainServiceData',
  function(MainServiceData){
    // don't make request, just serve up data
    console.log(MainServiceData);
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can just cache this without much difficulty. Add `cache : true` as such

```
angular.module('myApp')
.factory('MainService', ['$resource'
  function($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/example', {}, {
      get: {
        method: 'GET',
        cache : true // -- cached
      }
    });
  }
]);
```

I'd also recommend taking a look at [`$cacheFactory`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory) if you need a more involved solution.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I'm wondering if there's a way to remove some duplication in my code - i.e. the `MainService.get().$promise...` for each controller that needs the data from that request.

Comment: @cusejuice I had that a bit backwards. You can resolve your request in `app.run()` => assign to `$rootScope`, then place a `$watch` from your controller to have the value. There are a few ways you can do it.If you use `ui-router`, look into the `resolve` feature so you can inject this resultset before ctrl instantiation